# htaccess redirecting in some cases

Tags: html, .htaccess

I got an .htaccess file which redirects any request to index.html:

But i want, that only in case if somebody request to

```
www.mypage.com/login
```

that he will redirected to a file which is located in

```
/html/login.html
```

Here my file till now:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [NC]
```

How to implement this?
Thx!

Comment: I'd start by reading the Apache mod_rewrite docs.

Comment: RewriteEngine on should be before other Rewrite options

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ http://www.mypage.com/html/login.html [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [NC]
```

Comment: well done! can u also tell me how to turn the "www.mypage.com/html/login.html" into "ww.mypage.com/login"

Comment: @BigX_Jazz - So what you need to refirect `/html/login.html` into `/login` or vice versa? You cannot do both, as there would be a loop!

Comment: /html/login.html into /login

Comment: @BigX_Jazz - Replace 1st rule w/ `RewriteRule ^/?html/login.html$ http://www.mypage.com/login [NC,R=301,L]`